# User.Identity.Name is null after authenticate via WIF

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, wif

I'm using WIF to log in my appication. Everything seems to be ok (logging,redirecting to site etc),but when i try use `User.Identity.Name` in my cod exception is being thrown-`User` is null.Any ideas what i'm doing wrong? I work on VS 2012. Generated part in web.config looks like below:

```
  <system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration>
      <audienceUris>
        <add value="http://xxx/" />
      </audienceUris>     
      <issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <trustedIssuers>
          <add thumbprint="yyyy" name="https://zzz" />
        </trustedIssuers>
      </issuerNameRegistry>
    </identityConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel>
```

and:

```
  <system.identityModel.services>
    <federationConfiguration>
      <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" />
      <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="https://zzz/Secure/FederatedLogin.ashx" realm="http://xxx" requireHttps="false" />          
    </federationConfiguration>        
  </system.identityModel.services>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with WIF you should use Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name instead of User.Identity.Name.

Read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff872350.aspx to learn more about Windows Identity Foundation

Answer (score 2):

Check that the STS includes a **Name** claim for the user, else User.Identity.Name will be null.

Answer (score 0):

Instead I used:

```
namespace System.Security.Claims
{
    public static class System_Security_Claims_Extensions
    {
        public static string getName(this ClaimsIdentity ci)
        {
            foreach (Claim c in ci.Claims)
            {
                if (c.Type == ClaimTypes.Name)
                {
                    return c.Value;
                }
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

And used in this context
`((ClaimsIdentity)Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity).getName()`